# Check in Python if URL exists

Tags: python, facebook, url, http-status-code-404, python-requests

There are quite a few questions on SO about this topic, but none of which answers the following issue. Checking a normal URL with Python requests can be done easily like so:

```
print requests.head('https://www.facebook.com/pixabay').status_code
```

A status code of 200 means the page exists. In this particular case, it's a fan page on Facebook.

Trying this with a normal user profile on Facebook can work, too:

```
print requests.head('https://www.facebook.com/steinberger.simon').status_code
```

However, there are (seemingly random) user profiles that result in a 404 status code, despite a normal browser returns a 200:

```
print requests.head('https://www.facebook.com/drcarl').status_code
```

Using a custom header with User-Agent string or checking the URL with other methods all fails the same way:

```
import requests, urllib, urllib2

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/drcarl'

print requests.head(url).status_code

# using an User-Agent string
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36' }
print requests.head(url, headers=headers).status_code

# using GET instead if HEAD as request method
print requests.get(url, stream=True).status_code

# using urllib
print urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()

# using urllib2
try:
    r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print r.getcode()
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print e.code
```

There are other examples of URLs that inexplicably fail with the above methods. One of which is this: http://www.rajivbajaj.net/
It works perfectly with a 200 status code in all browsers, but results in a 403 for all Python methods described above.

I'm trying to write a reliable URL validator, but I can't see why those URLs are failing these tests. Any ideas?

Comment: You should ask Facebook about their HTTP API (if there is any). If a `HEAD` or `GET` returns `404 Not Found` in Python (or curl), there is nothing we can do.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, always getting a 200. Try to debug the request using `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` right before any request-ing.

Comment: Logging didn't give any new results. However, I found the cause for the failing FB URLs: non public profiles are returned as 404 when not authenticated on Facebook.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the difference between the browser and the python written code is the underlying HTTP request.
The python code could not work should because the constructed HTTP request does not exactly like the one generated by browser.

Add customer headers (using the one you provided)

```
print requests.get(url, headers=headers).status_code
```

It works in my local side for url **http://www.rajivbajaj.net/**, to get 200.

In this example, I guess the web site has done something special to some user-agent.

Comment: *lol* I don't believe this! That is probably the only combination of request method+header that I seem to have missed! E.g. a HEAD request doesn't work with this header - still a 403. Thanks Jacky!!

By the way: I also find the cause of the Facebook issue: when not authenticated, Facebook issues for non-public profiles a 404. That's weirdly incorrect by Facebook, but ok, if one knows ...

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you:

```py
def check_site_exist(self, url):
    try:
        url_parts = urlparse(url)
        request = requests.head("://".join([url_parts.scheme, url_parts.netloc]))
        return request.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful when they show required imports.